# Symfony2 - How to not remove current session when login/logout with FOS User Bundle

Tags: session, symfony, shopping-cart, fosuserbundle

I build an e-commerce and I have a small but boring problem. To command your cart, you must be logged in, so I have added a rule in security who redirect user in login page if he's not logged in. But after login (or logout), the cart is cleared. The cart is recovered by compare the session ID and the session ID stored in the database (one cart in database corresponds to one product in the user cart). I precise I use FOSUserBundle. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but you can try to add the following in your file `security.yml`:

```
security:
    session_fixation_strategy: none

    # ...
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt make a difference - the session Id was changed when FOSUserBundle logged me out.

Comment: I have not used FOSUser for a long time now. I do not think but it is possible that something has changed in the bundle which interfere with this behaviour. In all cases, remember to reset your cache.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check out knplabs e-commerce bundles **http://knpbundles.com/keyword/ecommerce**. They contain several bundles that may help you building your e-commerce solution including shopping card.

---

I believe you have to specify the **session cookie lifetime** in your application, read http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-cookie-lifetime

Comment: I can't use Sylius because my application is too specific. But it's no  the session cookie lifetime the problem, the problem is when I logout the session is cleared.
I have solved the problem for login: I set a "cartSessionId" in my session (and I get it instead of directly get session ID) and it it isn't removed by login.